# For a subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ , when does $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(H)\rvert$ divide $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G)\rvert$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Is it true that $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(H)\rvert$ divides $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G)\rvert$? What if we also assume $G$ is abelian? (I know that $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(H)\rvert \space \big| \space \lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G)\rvert$ if $G$ is cyclic).

Comment: This is relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9749/characterising-extendable-automorphisms

Answer (score 6):

It's not even true for abelian groups in general. Take $H=C_2\times C_2$ as a subgroup of $G=C_4\times C_2$. Then $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G)\rvert=8$, while $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(H)\rvert=6$.